# Unity Animator Works, but Character Doesn't Animate

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I haven't worked on my Unity project for awhile. When I returned and went into play mode, my character stopped animating correctly. I can move him around, but he's stuck in his A pose.

I checked the Animator tab to see what's up, and suprisingly it's working 100% as it's supposed to. So why isn't my character performing the animations?

I tried reimporting my model, then when that didn't work I went to Blender and re-exported my model to FBX --still didn't work. I also tried changing the Animation types and applying the changes (IIRC it was originally set to *"Generic"* back when the animations were working), but that didn't work either.

[Animation Type Dropdown Menu 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPjXv.png)

[Animation Type Dropdown Menu 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QMxD.png)

I'm honestly stumped. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, in my case it was the versions of my animation packages, you can try to downgrade all the related packages at **Window > Package Manager** to the version you had before you returned to work on this project